# How to make a control dock in a wpf

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make my menu bar fill the screen horizontally like a menu bar should look. When I run the program the window is set to maximize already but the menu bar only fills half the screen on top. I'm not sure how to fix this. So just to be clear I'm trying to make my controls fit to appearance based on the size of the window.

Heres the code:

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Royale" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" SizeToContent="Manual" WindowState="Maximized" xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<Window.Resources>
    <my1:Double x:Key="Width1">500</my1:Double>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid ShowGridLines="False" Width="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top"       Width="503" IsMainMenu="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <MenuItem Header="File" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <MenuItem Header="New">
                <MenuItem Header="New Camper" />
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
        <MenuItem Header="View" />
        <MenuItem Header="Add" />
    </Menu>
   </Grid>
   </Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `DockPanel`:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Button Content="Dock=Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Left"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button Content="LastChildFill=True"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: instead of grid or put a dockpanel on the grid. Sorry If i sound clueless, I never used vs10 before :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer - set your menu to use  `Grid.ColumnSpan="3"`, since you have 3 columns.

However, I would recommend nesting your "main" grid inside of a DockPanel or a second Grid (with 2 rows).  This way, as you add content (ie: add new columns to your grid), you won't have to constantly adjust your menu to compensate.